# Select and Create_If_Not_Available versus Create always on a table with Unique Constraint

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, unique-constraint

Please deal with this basic question.

I have a table T with unique constraint on composite columns "A" and "B".

While creating entry into T, I have two options:

**1. Select and Create_If_Not_Available**

a. Select * from T where A='a' and B='b'.
b. If no entry available, create a new entry (with handling of ConstraintViolation because of race condition), else move to next step.

**2. Create always**

a. Create entry into DB (With handling of `ConstraintViolation` and relying on Databases's unique constraint).

As per me, 2nd will have less queries being fired on DB and replies on database (outside the application code).

First makes a lot of unnecessary calls but has very little dependency on unique constraint of database.

Given high scale, which one should I prefer and why?

I am using Java, Hibernate and Oracle.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The things done by the database in step 2 will have to be done in step 1 anyway, so from a pure efficiency standpoint, step 2 is better. Why do you care about "dependency on unique constraints"? From an integrity perspective, you need them.

If your application is attempting to insert a lot of records for existing keys, it seems to me you have other problems.

Comment: Yes, application tries to create/insert/update frequently for existing keys.

Comment: Have you considered MERGE? It might be a compromise. Try it and measure results.